# RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl cannot be found but it's jar is added to pom.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb

i'm facing a lib problem... i guess i have a lib conflict anywhere but i cannot find it...

What did i do? I upgraded my Hibernate Libs from 4.x to 5.3.1 and switched from Java 8 to Java 10... i also upgraded my Spring libs to 5.0.4-RELEASE.

I found out that hibernate 5.3.1 needs some jaxb dependencies and so i added them but i still got this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:63) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:128) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:162) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:92) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:455) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.hbmJaxbContext(MappingBinder.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.doBind(MappingBinder.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.doBind(AbstractBinder.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl$1.addDocument(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:111) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:297) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Here are the jaxb libs i've added to my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The really strange thing for me is that in jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar i have found the class RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl?! So what's the problem?!

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok... i found the mistake... i missed another dependency... it was hidden in another exception at creating the spring context:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
     <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this! This was the only solution that worked for me on java 10.